# highlight a span by specific time(with Jquery):

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight a span by specific time with jquery.

for example:(highlight this line in 20 sec)

```
<span> highlight me slowly by specific time</span>

window.setTimeout(function() {
    // what do i must write here?
}, 20*1000);
```

I want this Result:

http://8pic.ir/images/sk9q76r96e3dc1rq4zo.swf

Comment: exactly i want to highlight a span tag by a time(like 20 sec) slowly

Comment: i mean w/ jquery. what have you done to solve this problem other than producing a prototype?

Comment: i'm new in j query,i just want to know how can i do some thing like this with j query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Have a look at this latest JS fiddle, I've changed the code to make sure it preserves the location of the span and also turned it into a plugin
http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/9UgEF/4/

**Original post**

Here is some sample code to get you started, you can see it in a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/9UgEF/2/

HTML

```
<span id="test">Do you see any Teletubbies in here?</span>​
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var seconds = 5;
  var el = $('span#test');
  var width = el.outerWidth();
  var height = el.outerHeight();
  var wrapper = $('<div>').css({
    width: width + 'px',
    height: height + 'px',
    position: 'relative'
  });
  var background = $('<div>').css({
    width: 0,
    height: height + 'px',
    position: 'absolute',
    background: '#0f0'
  });
  wrapper.append(background);
  wrapper.append(el.css('position','absolute'));
  $('body').append(wrapper);
  background.animate({width: '+=' + width},1000*seconds);

});​
```

It looks liks quite a lot of code something simple, but it was the easiest way I could think to more closely mimic your demo. If you were going to use this a lot it could be turned into a [jQuery plugin relatively easily](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html) - but you might want to alter my nesting slightly, perhaps giving the wrapper div #wrapper-[span ID] or something for later use.

Comment: cool, take a look at my edit with the most recent jsfiddle too

Comment: another question:what do i do for this(http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/7/)  (for multi line?) it's highlight all lines together?

Comment: that makes it more complicated ;) we'd either have to flow it into several rows, or consider highlighting one character at a time. does it need to be a smooth animation? - also, out of interest, what is this for?

Comment: thank u i got the solution:DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/32/

Comment: thats a nice solution for the 1 character at a time thing. how is it controlled to take an exact amount of time?

Comment: -@joevallender:look at this:http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/34/:look at this:http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/34/

Comment: -@joevallender:do u have any idea for this : http://jsfiddle.net/9UgEF/37/ (i use a special font for each word)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15814/discussion-between-joevallender-and-irsog)

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery needed for [timeouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). Use it like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // specify somethingto do in this anonymous function,
    // which will be called after 20 seconds
}, 20*1000);
```

Whether you use jQuery or not in the function is you choice.

---

To highlight slowly, you can use jQuery's animation queue. This also includes timeouts with [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), so use

```
$myspan.delay(20*1000).animate({"background-color": "red"}, "slow");
```

Watch out, as noted in the docs for the [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you will need a Color plugin or jQueryUI to animate colors.

Comment: i know,but how do i highlight my span tag slowly(from start to end)?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/animate/